# VB6 - Adding and searching for an item in sorted list - better performance

Tags: list

I need to maintain an old system written in vb6.
Currently in this system there is an sorted list of integers with approximately 1 million items. To locate an item, I use binary search to obtain the shortest response time.

I need to add new items to this list in runtime and these items are added to the end of the list, however the binary search requires that the list is sorted.

Currently the list is a User-Defined Data Types and the ordering is by the Code field

```
Private Type ProductDetails
ProdID as String
ProdName as String
Code as Double
End Type
```

The main requirement is the response time to find an item in whatever position it is.

Any idea or tip of this implementation will be very welcome.

thankful
Nadia

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Fastest way is with collection:

this is output from test sub:

```
creating 1.000.000 long product list
**done in 16,6219940185547 seconds**

searching list
fastest way (instant) if you know index (if you have ID)
ID0500000
 500000       ID0500000     This is product 500000
**done in 0 seconds**


searching by name (find item 500.000 which is in the middle od list
 500000       ID0500000     This is product 500000
**done in 0,425003051757813 seconds**


listing all items that have '12345' in their name
 12345        ID0012345     This is product 12345
 112345       ID0112345     This is product 112345
 123450       ID0123450     This is product 123450
 123451       ID0123451     This is product 123451
 123452       ID0123452     This is product 123452
 123453       ID0123453     This is product 123453
 123454       ID0123454     This is product 123454
 123455       ID0123455     This is product 123455
 123456       ID0123456     This is product 123456
 123457       ID0123457     This is product 123457
 123458       ID0123458     This is product 123458
 123459       ID0123459     This is product 123459
 212345       ID0212345     This is product 212345
 312345       ID0312345     This is product 312345
 412345       ID0412345     This is product 412345
 512345       ID0512345     This is product 512345
 612345       ID0612345     This is product 612345
 712345       ID0712345     This is product 712345
 812345       ID0812345     This is product 812345
 912345       ID0912345     This is product 912345
**done in 2,05299377441406 seconds**
```

so, if you load list in memory at the beginning of the app it should search fast enough

'following this code goes in module:

```
Option Explicit
Private Type ProductDetails
    ProdID As String
    ProdName As String
    Code As Double
End Type

Dim pdList As New Collection

Function genRndNr(nrPlaces)  'must be more then 10
    Dim prefix As String
    Dim suffix As String
    Dim pon As Integer
    prefix = Right("0000000000" + CStr(DateDiff("s", "2020-01-01", Now)), 10)
    suffix = Space(nrPlaces - 10)
    For pon = 1 To Len(suffix)
        Randomize
        Randomize Rnd * 1000000
        Mid(suffix, pon, 1) = CStr(Int(Rnd * 10))
    Next
    genRndNr = prefix + suffix
End Function


Sub test()
    Dim pd As ProductDetails
    Dim pdData As Variant
    Dim query As String
    Dim pon As Long
    Dim startT As Long
    
    
    Debug.Print "creating 1.000.000 long product list"
    startT = Timer
    For pon = 1 To 1000000
        pd.Code = pon
        pd.ProdID = "ID" + Right("0000000000" + CStr(pon), 7)    'id= from ID0000001 to ID1000000
        pd.ProdName = "This is product " + CStr(pon)             'product name
        pdData = Array(pd.Code, pd.ProdID, pd.ProdName)          'create array
        pdList.Add pdData, pd.ProdID                             'adding array to collection (pd.ID=index)
    Next
    Debug.Print "done in " + CStr(Timer - startT) + " seconds"
    Debug.Print
    Debug.Print
    
    
    Debug.Print "searching list"
    startT = Timer
    Debug.Print "fastest way (instant) if you know index (if you have ID)"
    query = "ID0500000"
    pdData = pdList(query)
    pd.Code = pdData(0)
    pd.ProdID = pdData(1)
    pd.ProdName = pdData(2)
    Debug.Print query
    Debug.Print pd.Code, pd.ProdID, pd.ProdName
    Debug.Print "done in " + CStr(Timer - startT) + " seconds"
    Debug.Print
    Debug.Print
    
    Debug.Print "searching by name (find item 500.000 which is in the middle od list"
    startT = Timer
    query = "This is product 500000"
    For Each pdData In pdList
        If query = pdData(2) Then
            pd.Code = pdData(0)
            pd.ProdID = pdData(1)
            pd.ProdName = pdData(2)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Debug.Print pd.Code, pd.ProdID, pd.ProdName
    Debug.Print "done in " + CStr(Timer - startT) + " seconds"
    Debug.Print
    Debug.Print
    
    
    Debug.Print "listing all items that have '12345' in their name"
    startT = Timer
    query = "*12345*"
    For Each pdData In pdList
        If pdData(2) Like query Then
            pd.Code = pdData(0)
            pd.ProdID = pdData(1)
            pd.ProdName = pdData(2)
            Debug.Print pd.Code, pd.ProdID, pd.ProdName
        End If
    Next
    Debug.Print "done in " + CStr(Timer - startT) + " seconds"
    Debug.Print
    Debug.Print
    
    
    
    'clear pd memory buffer
    Set pdList = Nothing
End Sub
```